# How to serialize an object to XML with multiple identical sibling elements

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I am trying to create the class structure that I can serialize into an XML file. Everything is working fine except for one section of my XML that must look like this:

```
<DeliveryAddress>
    <AddressLine>123 Main st</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>Ste 99</AddressLine>
</DeliveryAddress>
```

What would my class structure look like to make this possible?

```
Public Class DeliveryAddress
    Public Property AddressLine as new List(Of String)
End Class
```

The above works, but the address elements are just named 'String' instead of AddressLine when adding data like so:

```
Dim delAddr as new DeliveryAddress
delAddr.AddressLine.add("123 Main St")
delAddr.AddressLine.add("ste 99")
```

I feel like this should be simple but I'm not quite able to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "XmlElementAttribute" in front of the property. It works.

```
Public Class DeliveryAddress
    <XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable:=False)> _
    Public Property AddressLine As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

The output is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<DeliveryAddress xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<AddressLine>123 Main St</AddressLine>

<AddressLine>ste 99</AddressLine>

</DeliveryAddress>
```